# Make Thunderbird look like Outlook?

Tags: linux, email, microsoft-outlook, thunderbird, thunderbird-addon

I was using outlook for many years. I am trying to change my Thunderbird look like Outlook.

I found some of the settings

- Configure the layout of the Folder pane, message list pane, and message pane according to your preference.  (Menu -->View --> Toolbar/Folder/Layout)
- Change the Font

But is there any other list of settings do i need to change

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well they are different applications, so there will be differences, but I like to also add the (View --> Today pane) as Mini-Month.

If you also enable a calendar with [CalDav](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CalDAV) and the address book with [CardDav](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CardDAV), then you're getting there. As Thunderbird starts up with the tabs you close it with I keep the calendar in a second tab, and have mail and calendar right next to each other, syncing with my mail account, and therefore also with my phone :-)